# Watching a controller's properties from a directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to watch a controller's properties from it's associated directive from within the link function. The controller itself is set to the 'window' object on the $scope using controllerAs; here is the directive definition:

```
function windowDirective() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: template,
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: WindowCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'window',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      $scope.$watch('window.x', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // access x here
      });
    }
  };
}
```

And here is WindowCtrl

```
'use strict';
class WindowCtrl {
  move(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

module.exports = WindowCtrl;
```

`move(x, y)` is being called when I drag on a child directive - it is definitely being called and `this.x` and `this.y` are *definitely* being set on WindowCtrl. In addition, if I `console.dir` the `$scope` then fire `move()` a few times, I can open up the scope in chrome (because it's lazily evaluated) and see that `$scope.window.x` and `$scope.window.y` are indeed being set.

However, my `$scope.$watch` never actually fires aside from when it initially detects that `window.x` is undefined. Not really sure how to proceed. I did search and try all of the solutions I found but none of them seemed to have worked.

I'm using Angular 1.3.16.

NB: The access to `WindowCtrl.move()` is only ever from within Angular's digest cycle - see below - however using `$scope.$apply()` solves this. I'm not sure why this is the case. Could you explain? The below is a directive which is nested inside of the above directive. It will invoke the method at `onDrag`, which in my example points to `window.move(x, y);`

```
function windowHeaderDirective() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: template,
    replace: true,
    require: `^${windowDirective.$name}`,
    scope: {
      enableClose: '=actionClose',
      draggable: '=',
      onDrag: '&'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      $scope.close = $ctrl.close.bind($ctrl);
      let moving = false;
      $element.on('mousemove', function(event) {
        if(!moving) return
        const { x, y } = event;
        $scope.header.onDrag({ x, y });
        // $scope.$apply here will fix this issue, but why? Isn't $element.on within angular's digest cycle??
      });
      $element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
        moving = true;
      });
      $element.on('mouseup', function(event) {
        moving = false
      });
    },
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'header'
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure watching a controller As variable works exactly the way you're trying. Maybe reference: http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: I read that and it does actually work the way I've written it. The main issue appears to be that my `$element.on('...')` does not seem to trigger `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: Not too surprising, $element.on is a jquery thing, not necessarily an angular thing.

Comment: It's a jqlite thing as well; I don't have jquery in my solution. I would have assumed that jqlite would have been within the angular digest cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer:

It appears, due to my update, I answered the question myself, so;

`$element.on` does not appear to actually be in the angular digest cycle - this is fairly surprising for me, I assumed it would be. However, this essentially means that my code works as it should - it's just the changes to the variables on the controller are not apparent straight away. The way to fix this is to simply use either `ng-mousedown` et al, or `$scope.$apply` in the `$element.on` handler.

Answer (score 0):

In the $watch try using a function watcher like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $scope.window.x
 }, ...
```